# Copy Date to Clipboard onclick

Tags: javascript, date, clipboard

I might be making things overly complicated :p
But I can't get it to work.

I'm trying to copy "todays date"
to the clipboard

```
<a href="javascript:copydateToClipboard()">Date</a>
<script> 
function copydateToClipboard() {
Date.prototype.toShortFormat = function() {
    const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
                        "May", "Juni", "July", "August",
                        "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    const day = this.getDate()-1;
    const monthIndex = this.getMonth();
    const monthName = monthNames[monthIndex];
    const year = this.getFullYear();
    return `${year}_${monthName}_${day}`;  }
let anyDate = new Date(1528578000000);
console.log(anyDate.toShortFormat());
let today = new Date();
//copydate to clipboard
  const str = "${today}"
  const el = document.createElement('textarea')
  el.value = str
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '')
  el.style.position = 'absolute'
  el.style.left = '-9999px'
  document.body.appendChild(el)
  el.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
  document.body.removeChild(el)
}
</script>
```

Taken from an [url reform script](https://codepen.io/ryedai1/full/wvXjJQd).

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick="copydateToClipboard()">`

Comment: [execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) is deprecated, so look for [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard). -- Assign a function to `Date.prototype.toShortFormat` outside of your `copydateToClipboard` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
<a href="javascript:copydateToClipboard()">Date</a>
<script> 
function copydateToClipboard() {
  var nowd = new Date().toUTCString().slice(0,16);
  //const str = "${nowd}"
  const el = document.createElement('textarea')
  el.value = nowd
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '')
  el.style.position = 'absolute'
  el.style.left = '-9999px'
  document.body.appendChild(el)
  el.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
  document.body.removeChild(el)
}
</script>
```